# Zeus + Poseidon not running after update

Tags: wine, playonlinux

after my ubuntu was updated to 20.04 shortly, my Zeus + Posidon game, which i used to play via steam running on wine, is not starting any more. There is just a black screen.

I start the steam via:

wine ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Steam/drive_c/Program\ Files/Steam/steam.exe -no-browser +open steam://open/minigameslist

which outputs:

ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2020-11-01 11:23:04] Startup - updater built Oct 23 2020 13:30:23
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2020-11-01 11:23:04] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2020-11-01 11:23:04] 1. http://media4.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 100, source = 'update_hosts_cached.vdf'
[2020-11-01 11:23:04] Checking for update on startup
[2020-11-01 11:23:04] Checking for available update...
[2020-11-01 11:23:04] Downloading manifest: media4.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_win32
[2020-11-01 11:23:05] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_win32 version 1603487799, installed  version 1603487799, downloaded version 0
[2020-11-01 11:23:05] Nothing to do
[2020-11-01 11:23:05] Verifying installation...
[2020-11-01 11:23:05] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2020-11-01 11:23:10] Verification complete
IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process  pipe.0009:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\??\Z:\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
[2020-11-01 11:23:13] Background update loop checking for update. . .
[2020-11-01 11:23:13] Checking for available update...
[2020-11-01 11:23:13] Downloading manifest: media4.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_win32
0041:err:dc:CreateDCW no driver found for L"\\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0"
[2020-11-01 11:23:13] Download skipped by HTTP 304 Not Modified
[2020-11-01 11:23:13] Nothing to do
INTEL-MESA: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
INTEL-MESA: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
INTEL-MESA: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
INTEL-MESA: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {294935ce-f637-4e7c-a41b-ab255460b862} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {294935ce-f637-4e7c-a41b-ab255460b862} not registered
0009:err:ole:create_server class {294935ce-f637-4e7c-a41b-ab255460b862} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {294935ce-f637-4e7c-a41b-ab255460b862} could be created for context 0x17
IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process   pipe.0009:err:ole:RevokeDragDrop invalid hwnd 0001014E
IPC client is in my process, could/should be using an in-process pipe.

and starts steam as usual. When trying to start the game, i get a black screen only, sometimes even not able to Alt+Tab so i have to restart.

What can i do to diagnose the problem and get Zeus to run again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime i found out, that the problem seemed to be issues with the nvidia driver. After manually installing a suitable driver, everything works fine again.